# Android XML parser 3G issue: result string are splitted and duplicated

Tags: android, xml-parsing, 3g-network

I have to retrieve datas from a XML got from webservice.

I use SAX parser, like follow:

```
                URL url = new URL(this.pUrl);
                SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
                ProductsHandler handler = new ProductsHandler();
                xr.setContentHandler(handler);
                InputSource is = new InputSource(url.openStream());
                is.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
                xr.parse(is);
```

XML item:

```
<product>
    <id_product>4548</id_product>
    <name>Special snack 30gr chocolate</name>
    <price>15,00</price>
</product>
```

Handler snippet:

```
..
else if(localName.equals("name")){
            this.in_nome=true;
        }
..
else if(localName.equals("name")){
            this.in_nome=false;
        }
..
else if(this.in_name){
            xmlparsing.setNames(new String(ch , start , length));
        }
```

When i use WiFi connection, it works well.

If i use 3G connection, some item are splitted and duplicated.

e.g.

WiFi behaviour:

```
Product name: Special snack 30gr chocolate
```

3G behaviour:

```
Product Name: Special sna;
Product Name: Special snack 30gr chocolate;
```

This behaviour cause an issue in the products list (product id associated to wrong name).

How can i solve it?

Comment: Check the response.The data is not coming properly from server side .

Comment: @Anuja I checked the response on the browser of my device and it gives the right name

Comment: Try debugging the code and  inspect the value

Comment: I debugged the code of my handler. When i use 3G connection, the string is splitted and duplicated. I guess that is a 3G connection problem, not of the parser. It seems that the connection is unstable and sometimes accuses a decline, so the reading of the XML is fragmentary. Is a stupid thought?

Comment: I guess you're right. The truncate products change sometimes ... i'm sure that's a connection problem, not of the parser or malformed xml ... it seems unsolvable ( obviously i hope i'm wrong :D )